# Writing .npy (numpy binary format) from java

Tags: java, python, serialization, numpy

Is there a library to create npy file in java?

I'm looking for a method to write large matrices in java, to be read using python code.

npy seems like a good option, as it doesn't add additional dependencies in the python side, and the format is documented.

I considered hdf5 format, but the dependency on native libraries makes the deployment harder.

Comment: npy format is very simple and documented. You can easily write it yourself.

Comment: ended up using hdf5 - jmatio was somewhat buggy with large memory allocations

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples/blob/master/nd4j-examples/src/main/java/org/nd4j/examples/Nd4jEx16_Serialization.java#L37

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a library to do this but you could look at the specification, or possibly use the matlab format as an intermediate, for which there appears to be at least one java library:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10759-jmatio-matlabs-mat-file-io-in-java

I've never done this, but it might work for you and then you can read those files via:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html

Comment: the python side requires the native hdf5 libraries.

Comment: @OphirYoktan HDF5 is not a dependency of Scipy and the .mat format does not rely on it either: http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf

Comment: @joshAdel  do you have any solution in java to read from .npy file

Answer (score 11):

We've encountered the same problem a while ago and implemented both NPY and [NPZ](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html#conventions) formats in Kotlin as part of the [`npy`](https://github.com/JetBrains-Research/npy) library.

The current version (0.2.0) has a number of limitations. Specifically, it doesn't support

- multidimensional arrays
- structured arrays
- unsigned integral types and [some others](https://github.com/JetBrains-Research/npy#limitations).

---

Java code:

```java
Path filePath = new File("my.npz").toPath();
int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int[] shape = {2, 3};
try (NpzFile.Writer writer = NpzFile.write(filePath, true)) {
    writer.write("my-entry", values, shape);
}
```

Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.bio</groupId>
    <artifactId>npy</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Call me stupid, but how is it imported? import org.jetbrains.bio.NpyFile?